# How do I extract and save links in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

As a newbie to Selenium, my first attempt is save all the links on a page. The code I have is from an example that I can't get to work.
Whats am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.python.org"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.minimize_window()

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By. LINK_TEXT, "a")))


for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    if href is not None:
        print(href)

driver.quit()
```

Also, how do I save the links and be able to click on them when I need to.

And this is the error message I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/joe-2/Ubuntu-Storage1/Exuma-Snoops/RGD-code/link-test.py", line 21, in <module>
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By. LINK_TEXT, "a")))
  File "/home/joe-2/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two issues:**

1. All the links are not visible they are just present on the DOM. So, you need to change this `visibility_of_all_elements_located` to `presence_of_all_elements_located`
2. `By. LINK_TEXT, "a"` - this also is incorrect. There is no link in the DOM with value `a`. Change the locator strategy to `By.XPATH, "//a"`, this will locate all the anchor tags(`<a>`) in the DOM

So below line in incorrect:

```
links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By. LINK_TEXT, "a")))
```

**Change it as as below:**

```
links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a")))
```

Comment: I have to ask, how can I save these links and make them clickable at some point lazter in my code?

Comment: Didn't understand your question! All the links are already saved into a variable called `links`, you can access it whenever you want in your code.

Comment: not working for me, my code is as follows
links(0).click()
This just gives me the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/joe-2/Ubuntu-Storage1/Exuma-Snoops/RGD-code/link-test-2.py", line 24, in <module>
    links(0).click()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Ok this is a separate issue. Keep one issue per question. Please raise a new question for this issue and provide all the details, this way you will get answers from wider community.